# JS console.log() shows that my function itterated through all the if statements, but the elements being manipulated are not changing

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am not sure how best to explain this, but here is an example of my js file, with the corresponding body of the html file below. Ideally, I would like this to append the bar1, bar2, and bar3 to each of the three elements. Logically, I would think after running the first if statement, my js file would append the bar elements to the correct `<div>` element in the html file, then move to the next if statement. My thinking for why I wrote my function the way I did - I assumed after each if statement runs and appends to the intended element, then in the next if statement I can change a few things on the already created elements, then append them to a new element.

What happens when I run it:
If I inspect element on the page, only the last `<div>` element "pn-3bar-32" has children. However, the `console.log()` shows each if statement has been run through. Why is this? Still learning JS, so any help is appreciated.

JS file

```
window.onload = function () {

    var bar1 = this.document.createElement("div");
    var bar2 = this.document.createElement("div");
    var bar3 = this.document.createElement("div");

    if (this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-16")) {
        let menu = this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-16");
        var styles = 'background-color:black; width:16px; height:4px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px;'
        bar1.setAttribute('style', styles);
        bar2.setAttribute('style', styles);
        bar3.setAttribute('style', styles);
        menu.appendChild(bar1);
        menu.appendChild(bar2);
        menu.appendChild(bar3);
        console.log("1st if");
    }
    if (this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-24")) {
        let menu = this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-24");
        var styles = 'background-color:black; width:24px; height:5px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px;'
        bar1.setAttribute('style', styles);
        bar2.setAttribute('style', styles);
        bar3.setAttribute('style', styles);
        menu.appendChild(bar1);
        menu.appendChild(bar2);
        menu.appendChild(bar3);
        console.log("2nd if");
    }
    if (this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-32")) {
        let menu = this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-32");
        var styles = 'background-color:black; width:32px; height:6px; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;'
        bar1.setAttribute('style', styles);
        bar2.setAttribute('style', styles);
        bar3.setAttribute('style', styles);
        menu.appendChild(bar1);
        menu.appendChild(bar2);
        menu.appendChild(bar3);
        console.log("3rd if");
    }

}
```

HTML body

```
<body>

    <div id="pn-3bar-16"></div>

    <div id="pn-3bar-24"></div>

    <div id="pn-3bar-32"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: `this.document` <-- where do you learn that? there no no reason to use this

Comment: you only created 3 divs. Did you mean to create 3 for each node? You'd have to clone them then, appending them doesn't make them go away or append a copy. it appends that element. you're moving them, not copying html as a string.

Comment: You reference the same element. So when you append it to a new place, it moves to that place. You need to clone it

Comment: @Nikki9696 Ahh yes I did, I did not realize that it was moving the element. That makes much more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is you are appending the same elements over and over again. The element can only live in one place. So you need to clone them before you alter them.

```
if (this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-16")) {
    let menu = this.document.getElementById("pn-3bar-16");
    var styles = 'background-color:black; width:16px; height:4px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px;'
    const bar1Clone = bar1.cloneNode();
    const bar2Clone = bar2.cloneNode();
    const bar3Clone = bar3.cloneNode();
    bar1Clone.setAttribute('style', styles);
    bar2Clone.setAttribute('style', styles);
    bar3Clone.setAttribute('style', styles);
    menu.appendChild(bar1Clone);
    menu.appendChild(bar2Clone);
    menu.appendChild(bar3Clone);
    console.log("1st if");
}
```

What I would do:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {

    var bars = [
      document.createElement("div"),
      document.createElement("div"),
      document.createElement("div")
    ]

    var data = {
      'pn-3bar-16': 'background-color:black; width:16px; height:4px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px;',
      'pn-3bar-24': 'background-color:black; width:24px; height:5px; margin-top:1px; margin-bottom:1px;',
      'pn-3bar-32': 'background-color:black; width:32px; height:6px; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px;'
    }

    Object.entries(data).forEach( function (dt) {
      var menu = document.getElementById(dt[0])
      if (menu) {
        bars.forEach(function(bar){
           const bc = bar.cloneNode()
           bc.setAttribute('style', dt[1])
           menu.appendChild(bc)
        })
      }
    }) 
})
```

```html
<div id="pn-3bar-16"></div>
<div id="pn-3bar-24"></div>
<div id="pn-3bar-32"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write this up, this makes much more sense now. Additionally, your way of approaching this seems much more efficient, I love the use of arrays. Thanks for all the help!